# Project Euler #11 java. Not getting the right answer

Tags: java

I have some problems with [Problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) on Project Euler.
I manage to get an answer, but it's not the right one. I'm getting `51267216`.
This is found by the `greatestVert` method. I think the problem is located in the `greatestDiaglonal` method, but I'm not quite sure. Can somebody check if my algorithm is correct?

The task is to find out what the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in any direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) is in the 20x20 grid.

```
package euler;

public class Problem11 {

int num1, num2, num3, num4;
int highestNum1, highestNum2, highestNum3, highestNum4;

private int sum = 0;

String[] l = {
"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08",
"49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00",
"81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65",
"52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91",
"22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80",
"24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50",
"32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70",
"67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21",
"24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72",
"21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95",
"78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92",
"16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57",
"86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58",
"19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40",
"04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66",
"88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69",
"04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36",
"20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16",
"20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54",
"01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"
};

int greatestSide() {
    for(int i = 0;i<=19;i++) {
        for(int n = 0;n<=l[i].length()-12;n+=3) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(3+n,6+n).trim());
            num3 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(6+n,9+n).trim());
            num4 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(9+n,12+n).trim());

            if(num1*num2*num3*num4 > sum) {
                sum = num1*num2*num3*num4;
                highestNum1 = num1;
                highestNum2 = num2;
                highestNum3 = num3;
                highestNum4 = num4;
            }   
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int greatestVert() {
    for(int i = 0; i<=16; i++) {
        for(int n = 0; n<=l[i].length()-3; n+=3) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+1].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());
            num3 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+2].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());
            num4 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+3].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());

            if(num1*num2*num3*num4 > sum) {
                sum = num1*num2*num3*num4;
                highestNum1 = num1;
                highestNum2 = num2;
                highestNum3 = num3;
                highestNum4 = num4;
            }   
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int greatestDiagonal() {
    for(int i = 19; i>=3; i--) {
        for(int n = 0; n<=l[i].length()-12; n+=3) {
            num4 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(9+n,12+n).trim());
            num3 = Integer.parseInt(l[i-1].substring(6+n,9+n).trim());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(l[i-2].substring(3+n,6+n).trim());
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(l[i-3].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());

            if(num1*num2*num3*num4 > sum) {
                sum = num1*num2*num3*num4;
                highestNum1 = num1;
                highestNum2 = num2;
                highestNum3 = num3;
                highestNum4 = num4;
            }   
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i>=16; i++) {
        for(int n = 0; n<=l[i].length()-12; n+=3) {
            num4 = Integer.parseInt(l[i].substring(9+n,12+n).trim());
            num3 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+1].substring(6+n,9+n).trim());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+2].substring(3+n,6+n).trim());
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(l[i+3].substring(0+n,3+n).trim());

            if(num1*num2*num3*num4 > sum) {
                sum = num1*num2*num3*num4;
                highestNum1 = num1;
                highestNum2 = num2;
                highestNum3 = num3;
                highestNum4 = num4;
            }   
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Problem11 prog = new Problem11();

    prog.greatestSide();
    prog.greatestVert();
    prog.greatestDiagonal();
    System.out.println(prog.sum);
    System.out.println(prog.highestNum1);
    System.out.println(prog.highestNum2);
    System.out.println(prog.highestNum3);
    System.out.println(prog.highestNum4);
}
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `String.split()`?

Comment: Why do you expect your error to be in `greatestDiagonal()` when you get the wrong result from `greatestVert()` and none of those methods call each other?

Comment: @jlordo Sounds like they are getting the appropriate answer in greatestVert, but it is not the appropriate answer for the problem, on account of an error in greatestDiagonal that is keeping the overall answer from being the result of greatestDiagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are omitting to scan one direction of diagonals:

```
for(int i = 0; i>=16; i++) {
```

doesn't run at all. You meant `i <= 16` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that firstly converts the `String` to a 2D array:

```
public class P11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";
        int n = 20;
        int a[][] = getMatrixOfIntegers(input, n);
        System.out.println(maxProduct(a));
    }

    private static long maxProduct(int a[][]) {
        int size = a.length - 4;
        int l = a.length - 1;
        long pMax = 1;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++ ) {
                int prodDiag1 = a[i][j]*a[i+1][j+1]*a[i+2][j+2]*a[i+3][j+3];
                if ( pMax < prodDiag1 ) {
                    pMax = prodDiag1;
                }
                int prodCol = a[i][j]*a[i+1][j]*a[i+2][j]*a[i+3][j];
                if ( pMax < prodCol ) {
                    pMax = prodCol;
                }
                int prodRow = a[i][j]*a[i][j+1]*a[i][j+2]*a[i][j+3];
                if ( pMax < prodRow ) {
                    pMax = prodRow;
                }
                int prodDiag2 = a[i][l-j]*a[i+1][l-j-1]*a[i+2][l-j-2]*a[i+3][l-j-3];
                if ( pMax < prodDiag2 ) {
                    pMax = prodDiag2;
                }               
            }
        }
        return pMax;
    }

    private static int[][] getMatrixOfIntegers(String input, int n) {
        String m[] = input.split(" ");
        int a[][] = new int[n][n];      
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n*n ; i++ ) {
            a[i/n][i%n] = Integer.parseInt(m[i]);
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

**Time** for `maxProduct`: 0.2 ms